# Performance of bitwise & on longs vs ints on 64 bit

Tags: c#, .net

It seems that when performing an `&` operation between two `long`s it takes the same amount of time as the equivalent operation inside 4 32bit `int`s.

For example

```
long1 & long2
```

Takes as long as

```
int1 & int2
int3 & int4
```

This is running on a 64bit OS and targeting 64bit .net.

In theory, this should be twice as fast. Has anyone encountered this previously?

**EDIT**

As a simplification, imagine I have two lots of 64 bits of data. I take those 64 bits and put them into a `long`, and perform a bitwise `&` on those two.

I also take those two sets of data, and put the 64 bits into two 32 bit `int` values and perform **two** `&`s. I expect to see the `long` `&` operation running faster than the `int` `&` operation.

Comment: "In theory, this should be twice as fast" - what do you base that on? Both will be done in the same 64bit registers, no?

Comment: I am **very** suspect of how you are measuring this. I also think it's quite an oversight to not mention your processor when asking a question about your computer's 64 bit performance...

Comment: @Mitch - Well, if i divide the contents of a long into two int32s, then it will only require one & vs. 2.

Comment: @Mania - Unit tests over 1,000,000 bits which have been pre-converted to int32 or int64 appropriately. The same algorithm in C++ yields roughly half the time taken for long & vs. int &. The CPU is a core i5 or something, although given that I've tested with C++, I don't believe the cpu is incapable of the & that I'm after.

Comment: @Khanzor thank you, could you please list the C# disassembly? My guess: C++ has nicely unrolled the loop, allowing the processor to perform the 64 bit ops in parallel. C# I'm guessing has not, meaning the processor can perform the 32 ops in parallel at the same rate as it can perform the single 64 bit op. But that's just a guess - really we need to see the disassembly of _at least_ the poor performing C# 64 bit code to draw any real conclusions.

Comment: In theory, I don't imagine it would be difficult to boil your code down to a small, simple benchmark, port it to C# and C++, and compare the results for one 64-bit longlong vs two 32-bit longs.  I'd be curious about the results :)

Comment: What is the speed difference between the c++ and c# versions? Are you addressing arrays in c#? It's quite possible that the safety checking (bounds, etc) uses more processor than the bitwise function, causing you to see the same benchmark, when really all you end up comparing is the safety checking between the 64 bit and 32 bit. The other likely issue is that the compiler notices that you're doing 32 bit compares repeatedly, unrolls the loop, and combines them into 64 bit operations. It's got a lot of optimization. The disassembly, as Mania points out, should give you answers to your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce the problem.

My test was as follows (int version shown):

```
// deliberately made hard to optimise without whole program optimisation
public static int[] data = new int[1000000]; // long[] when testing long

// I happened to have a winforms app open, feel free to make this a console app..
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    long best = long.MaxValue;
    for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
    {
        Stopwatch timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        int a1 = ~0, b1 = 0x55555555, c1 = 0x12345678; // varies: see below
        int a2 = ~0, b2 = 0x55555555, c2 = 0x12345678;
        int[] d = data; // long[] when testing long
        for (int i = 0; i < d.Length; i++)
        {
            int v = d[i]; // long when testing long, see below
            a1 &= v; a2 &= v;
            b1 &= v; b2 &= v;
            c1 &= v; c2 &= v;
        }
        // don't average times: we want the result with minimal context switching
        best = Math.Min(best, timer.ElapsedTicks); 
        button1.Text = best.ToString() + ":" + (a1 + a2 + b1 + b2 + c1 + c2).ToString("X8");
    }
}
```

For testing longs `a1` and `a2` etc are merged, giving:

```
long a = ~0, b = 0x5555555555555555, c = 0x1234567812345678;
```

Running the two programs on my laptop (i7 Q720) as a release build **outside** of VS (.NET 4.5) I got the following times:

**int:** 2238, **long:** 1924

Now considering there's a huge amount of loop overhead, and that the `long` version is working with twice as much data (8mb vs 4mb), it still comes out clearly ahead. So I have no reason to believe that C# is not making full use of the processor's 64 bit bitops.

But we really shouldn't be benching it in the first place. If there's a concern, simply check the jited code (Debug -> Windows -> Disassembly). Ensure the compiler's using the instructions you expect it to use, and move on.

Attempting to measure the performance of those individual instructions on your processor (and this could well be specific to your processor model) in anything other than assembler is a very bad idea - and from within a jit compiled language like C#, beyond futile. But there's no need to anyway, as it's all in [Intel's optimisation handbook](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/doc/manual/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.pdf) should you need to know.

To this end, here's the disassembly of the `a &=` for the `long` version of the program on x64 (release, but inside of debugger - unsure if this affects the assembly, but it certainly affects the performance):

```
00000111  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rsp+60h] ; a &= v
00000116  mov         rax,qword ptr [rsp+38h] 
0000011b  and         rax,rcx 
0000011e  mov         qword ptr [rsp+38h],rax
```

As you can see there's a single 64 bit and operation as expected, along with three 64 bit moves. So far so good, and exactly half the number of ops of the `int` version:

```
00000122  mov         ecx,dword ptr [rsp+5Ch] ; a1 &= v
00000126  mov         eax,dword ptr [rsp+38h] 
0000012a  and         eax,ecx 
0000012c  mov         dword ptr [rsp+38h],eax 
00000130  mov         ecx,dword ptr [rsp+5Ch] ; a2 &= v
00000134  mov         eax,dword ptr [rsp+44h] 
00000138  and         eax,ecx 
0000013a  mov         dword ptr [rsp+44h],eax
```

I can only conclude that the problem you're seeing is specific to something about your test suite, build options, processor... or quite possibly, that the `&` isn't the point of contention you believe it to be. HTH.

Comment: I can't reproduce my timings either. I just rewrote this with a simpler version, and couldn't reproduce. I had a look at the dissassembly, and it is indeed only performing a single and.

Answer (score 5):

I can't reproduce your timings. The following code generates two arrays: one of 1,000,000 longs, and one with 2,000,000 ints. Then it loops through the arrays, applying the `&` operator to successive values. It keeps a running sum and outputs it, just to make sure that the compiler doesn't decide to remove the loop entirely because it isn't doing anything.

Over dozens of successive runs, the `long` loop is at least twice as fast as the `int` loop. This is running on a Core 2 Quad with Windows 8 Developer Preview and Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview. Program is compiled with "Any CPU", and run in 64 bit mode. All testing done using Ctrl+F5 so that the debugger isn't involved.

```
        int numLongs = 1000000;
        int numInts = 2*numLongs;
        var longs = new long[numLongs];
        var ints = new int[numInts];
        Random rnd = new Random();
        // generate values
        for (int i = 0; i < numLongs; ++i)
        {
            int i1 = rnd.Next();
            int i2 = rnd.Next();
            ints[2 * i] = i1;
            ints[2 * i + 1] = i2;
            long l = i1;
            l = (l << 32) | (uint)i2;
            longs[i] = l;
        }

        // time operations.
        int isum = 0;
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < numInts; i += 2)
        {
            isum += ints[i] & ints[i + 1];
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Ints: {0} ms. isum = {1}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, isum);

        long lsum = 0;
        int halfLongs = numLongs / 2;
        sw.Restart();
        for (int i = 0; i < halfLongs; i += 2)
        {
            lsum += longs[i] & longs[i + 1];
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Longs: {0} ms. lsum = {1}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, lsum);
```